# Installing package without IDE on Lazarus from command line

Tags: ide, package, lazarus, fpc

I am trying to automate installing of my package to IDE from the command line using ([this](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Install_IDE_packages_without_the_IDE)) article.

When using IDE the package is installed correctly and my components appear on Lazarus palette.
To verify the article steps, after installation with IDE I copied `idemake.cfg`, `packagefiles.xml` and `staticpackages.inc` files from `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\lazarus` to a temp folder, so I have my package registered there.

Then tried without success:
1. uninstalled my package from IDE
2. called `make clean all` from `c:\Lazarus`
3. called `lazbuild` and built my package
4. copied all the kept files (`idemake.cfg`, `packagefiles.xml` and `staticpackages.inc`) to `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\lazarus`
5. copied kept `idemake.cfg` to `c:\Lazarus`
6. created `.lpl` file for my package and placed that in `C:\Lazarus\packager\globallinks`
7. finally called `make idepkg` from `C:\Lazarus`
8. alternatively tried `make bigide` and `lazbuild --build-ide=` with same result

When Lazarus IDE was built and started I could see my package among the installed packages but marked with the `green "+"`. The palette also missed my components.
If I select then `Tool -> Build Lazarus with profile: Build IDE with Packages`, this makes my package installed correctly after IDE is rebuilt the second time.

Version info:

> Lazarus: 0.9.30.2
>      FPC: 2.4.4
>      OS: Win 7

Am I missing something? Is there alternative to register packages from the command line without IDE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Lazbuild in current Lazarus (at least as far back as 1.0RC1) has been extended to be able to install packages.
For this, you can use the --add-package and --build-ide together.
See [the lazbuild wiki article](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/lazbuild)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this possibility will appear only in 1.1 according to the article you mentioned: `add package(s) to list of installed packages (combine with --build-ide to rebuild IDE). Since 1.1.`. I checked `Lazbuild` from 1.0 and that didn't have the --add-package switch.

Comment: Sorry about that, must have misremembered the version then.